# Loosing reference to state when listening to characteristics

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

So I've tried multiple solutions to store states but for some reason I can't figure out why I'm loosing the (latest) state of some context. I'm using the following function to get an update on a specific characteristic (I also tried the .monitor() directly on the characteristic).

```
// This is in the BluetoothProvider
device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
    service.uuid,
    characteristic.uuid,
    onUpdate)
```

Further I have a function to check the state:

```
// This is in the BluetoothProvider
const updating = () => {
    if (currentMatch != null && currentPerson != null) {
        console.log('found person')
    } else {
        console.log('no person')
    }
}
```

The properties are stored in a reducer with an API/Data `MatchProvider` provider:

```
const { currentMatch, currentPerson } = useContext(MatchDataContext)
```

The `onUpdate` function:

```
const onUpdate = (
    error: BleError | null,
    characteristic: Characteristic | null
) => {
    updating()
}
```

The provider is in the the correct place:

```
<MatchProvider>
    <BluetoothProvider>
      <Routes>
      </Routes>
    </BluetoothProvider>
  </MatchProvider>
```

I've tried moving it to another component/provider/redux it doesn't matter. The onUpdate function just can't get the correct state. The UI works perfectly and the state is stored but the `onUpdate` method never gets the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the fix, what I did was add the following to the `BluetoothProvider`

```
const matchRef = useRef(currentMatch);
const personRef = useRef(currentPerson);

React.useEffect(() => {
    matchRef.current = currentMatch
    personRef.current = currentPerson
}, [currentMatch, currentPerson]);
```

This allowed me to listen to the updates from the `MatchDataContext` and store the references. Because down the file I had a subscription that was triggered when the bluetooth device received a new message, and this wasn't up-to-date on the latest state.

```
const onUpdate = (
    error: BleError | null,
    characteristic: Characteristic | null
) => {
    if (matchRef.current != null && personRef.current != null) {
        console.log('using match', JSON.stringify(matchRef.current, null, 2))
    }
}
```

For some reason all debugging tools indicated that the value was there, in the `BluetoothProvider` but when I called the property it was null.